# Rails ActiveRecord - query by great-grandchild's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I find `Parent` via their `GreatGrandChild`'s attribute for the following setup:

```
Parent has_many :children
Child belongs_to :parent, has_many :grand_children
GrandChild belongs_to :child, has_many :great_grand_children
GreatGrandChild belongs_to :grand_child

Parent.where(
  children: {
    grand_children: {
      great_grand_children: {:name => "foo"}
    }
  }
)
```

And how do I when do I use `join` or `preload` or `eager_load` or `includes`, and what happens if `Child`/`GrandChild`/`GreatGrandChild` is a polymorphic model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to join your required tables telling rails which path to take.

```
Parent.joins(children: { grand_children: :great_grand_children })
```

This can be simplified if you add this information into your models.

```
Parent.has_many :grand_children, through: :children
Parent.has_many :great_grand_children, through: :grand_children
```

After that a single join is enough, but in the background it will do the same thing

```
Parent.joins(:great_grand_children)
```

Now that all the tables are being joined, we can add the where condition. Join already knows where the tables come from, so no need to specify it again.

```
Parent.joins(:great_grand_children).where(great_grand_children: { name: 'foo' })
```

Replace `joins` with `includes` or similar as needed.

Polymorphism will probably make the situation more complicated, but it's hard to say how from the little information you've provided.

Comment: thank you so much for the info! Thanks it does work!

Comment: Would you know about what syntax to go for, in something like `GrandChild.preload(children: :parents).where(child: {parent_id: 1})`? in my case, `Child` model is polymorphic in that one model is actually called `Child` when another one is called say `Bar`

Comment: If I remember correctly, joining polymorphic associations is not supported out of the box. You'll have to either create separate associations for each class or write raw sql. Polymorphism is not a magic bullet and while making some things easier will make others more complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does cause some headache!